# form a matrix by picking row with maximum value at first place from a matrix whose each element has various rows with 3 columns each

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix `Inter[i,j]` whose each element has a set of rows with 3 columns each.

for eg. `Inter[15,40]= {{0,0,0},{1,1,3}}`, `Inter[32,64]={{0,0,0},{1,1,3},{2,2,3}}` and so on

Now i want a matrix `MaxGG[i,j]` by picking a row from `Inter[i,j]` that has maximum value at the first place.

for eg `MaxGG[15,40]` should give me `{1,1,3}`. similarly `MaxGG[32,64]={2,2,3}`.
When i am giving this code,it does not give me the right answer:

```
MaxGG[i_, j_] := Cases[Inter[i, j], {Max@Inter[i, j][[All, 1]], _, _}];
```

Please suggest me what is wrong with this code and please provide me with the correct code for this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `Cases` will return a list of all matching cases :-

```
Inter[15, 40] = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 3}};
Inter[32, 64] = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 3}};

MaxGG[i_, j_] := Cases[Inter[i, j], {Max@Inter[i, j][[All, 1]], _, _}]

MaxGG[32, 64]
```

> {{2, 2, 3}}

You can lose the outer brackets by selecting the first match :-

```
MaxGG[i_, j_] := First@Cases[Inter[i, j], {Max@Inter[i, j][[All, 1]], _, _}]

MaxGG[32, 64]
```

> {2, 2, 3}

The function can also be simplified :-

```
MaxGG[i_, j_] := First@Reverse@Sort@Inter[i, j]

MaxGG[32, 64]
```

> {2, 2, 3}